# Permitir Multiplos Usuarios por Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

Por exemplo, o `Google` permite que você mantenha `n` contas do `Google` amarzenadas no seu `browser`.

No caso do `Google`, ele cria uma variavel de controle chamada `authuser` que recebe um `inteiro`, ele passa esta variavel na url, seja através de uma rota ou na queryString e a utiliza para identificar qual o `login` o usuario está utilizando naquela aba.

Gostaria de fazer algo semelhante com `ASP.NET Identity`

Answer (score 0):

Talvez tenha frameworks que faça isso que você deseja, nunca precisei então não pesquisei, mas penso agora em uma forma simples de resolver isso, e funciona independete da versão e se for sistema legado ou não. Basta gerenciar o cookie. Por exemplo, no Asp.Net, normalmente o nome do cookie padrão é ".ASPXAUTH", quando seu sistema for adicionar um novo usuário, você copiar o valor do cookie ".ASPXAUTH" para um novo cookie, como por exemplo "User1" e remove o cookie de autenticação e redireciona para página de login. Após o login, sempre que for trocar de usuário, basta trocar os valores dos cookies do "User1" e ".ASPXAUTH". É simples, mas acho que funciona.